# Make one flex item fixed width and its siblings all equal size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have four list items and I want three of them to stay the same size and the other one to be at with of 300px.

**My HTML:**

```
   <ul class="test">
      <li class="desc">Test description</li>
      <li class="test">Test</li>
      <li class="test">Test</li>
      <li class="test">Test</li>
    </ul>
```

**My SASS:**

```
      ul.test {
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        flex-direction: row;
        display: flex;
      }

      li.desc{
        width: 300px;
      }

      li.test{
        background: green;
        flex: 1 0 auto
      }
```

I want the first li to be 300px in width and then the other three to be the same size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
ul.test {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li.desc {
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;           /* disable default shrinking behavior */
  background-color: orange;
}

li.test {
  flex: 1;                  /* distribute free space evenly among items */
  background: lightgreen;
}
li{ border-right: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<ul class="test">
  <li class="desc">Test description</li>
  <li class="test">Test</li>
  <li class="test">Test</li>
  <li class="test">Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I increased the text in one field and the box increase in width. How do you make the three li's on the right stay the same size?

Comment: Try this on those three items instead: `flex: 0 0 calc(33% - 100px);` That sets each item to 1/3 the space in the container, minus 1/3 of the fixed sibling.

Comment: thank you. I dont understand why you had to set min width to 0?

Comment: I posted a link with the explanation in your plunkr demo. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276

Comment: Thank you.  Made my day!